# is Lucene + classic query search syntax same as using AND

Tags: java, lucene

A Lucene query of the form

```
field1:+"term1" field2:+"term2"
```

seems to be equivalent to

```
field1:"term1" OR field2:"term2"
```

I expected  it to be equivalent to

```
field1:"term1" AND field2:"term2"
```

(i.e for my particular query on my database query 1 and 2 are returning 10 records, whereas query 3 is returning 6 records, I would expect query 2 to only return six records)

Im aware that if there is no *OR* or *AND* it defaults to *OR* but I thought the + means that term has to match, otherwise what is the point of the +
What am i misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 2):

That query doesn't look equivalent to either of those, to me.

```
field1:+"term1" field2:+"term2"
```

Is just invalid syntax, and the standard QueryParser does kick out a `ParseException` for it (maybe your code is swallowing the exception silently or something?).

It should be:

```
+field1:"term1" +field2:"term2"
```

Comment: Are you sure because on https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html the example shows title:(+return +"pink panther"), i.e the plus is before the term not the field ?

Comment: Absolutely sure, yes. `field1:(+"term1")` is valid (though the + is meaningless). `field1:+"term1"` is not.

Comment: okay that is probably it then, but how I could deuce that form the Lucene docs I do not know.

Comment: Im stil having no luck with this, but I am testing via a web interface maybe that is causing an issue, is there a website where I could  test out lucene syntax.